# Read text file values and assign it to each value to variable

Tags: python

I want to read text file and find the words that starts with 56 in below text and pass each word to a variable and pass to a python file as a parameters.

My sample text file content -

```
51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8
56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03
56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07
51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:54:80
56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01
56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:03
```

I like to pass to python file as

```
mytestfile.py var1 var2 var3
```

var1 should have value 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03
var2 should have value 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07
var3 should have value 56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01

so on

I wrote code something like below but not working

[#var1 = "51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8"]
[#var2 = "51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:ea"]

```
   filepath = '/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file.txt'  
       with open(filepath) as fp:  
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt = 1
   while line:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
       line = fp.readline()
       cnt += 1
```

## execute "run create volume script" do

```
    command "python SDFlexnimblevolcreate.py #{var1} #{node['ilorest']['Test0']} #{var2} #{node['ilorest']['Test1']} 
    cwd "#{platformdirectory}"
    live_stream true
```

end

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that you need to pass parameters for `mytestfile.py` in a such way?

Comment: I  mean as a variable like mytestfile.py var1 var2 var3 var4. I want to assign it to variable that should increase for each value

Answer (score 0):

So this code prints string of required variables:

```
# a.py
with open('file.txt') as f:
    result = ' '.join(map(lambda x: f'<{x}>',
                          filter(lambda x: x.startswith('56'),
                                 map(str.strip, f))))
    print(result, end='')
```

**Output**:

```
<56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03> <56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07> <56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01> <56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:03>
```

You can pass result of this program using `xargs` to some another python program. For example if you have simple program which prints their arguments:

```
# b.py  
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

Than just type in shell:

```
python3 a.py | xargs python3 b.py
```

**Output**:

```
['b.py', '<56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03> <56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07> <56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01> <56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:03>']
```

Comment: how to do that using pipe?

Comment: Please, read this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). You can pass the result of this script to `mytestfile.py` using pipeline. I will add an example soon.

Comment: But the OP deosn't want a pipe, they want the output to be passed as command-line arguments. (This is probably misdirected, though.) The solution to that is `xargs`, or you can run the second program as a subprocess from the first.

Comment: Still *probably* not right, take out the `-0` (or actually print null-separated output from the first script).

Comment: Thanks..Can we use something like Arrays or list to hold the values in variables?

Comment: @RamKrishna what do you mean?

Comment: I reposed my requirement..please check if u can help

Comment: @RamKrishna I don't see some special changes. Maybe you can provide some test examples to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to run your `mytestfile.py` once for each line that starts with '56:', like this:

```
python mytestfile.py 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03
python mytestfile.py 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07
python mytestfile.py 56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01
```

Or do you want to run it one time only, giving it all values from the file as arguments, e.g., with your example data:

```
python mytestfile.py 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07 56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01
```

If it is the former (one run per matching line), the easiest way is:

```
grep '^56' textfile | xargs python mytestfile.py
```

otherwise, you could do this:

```
python mytestfile.py `grep '^56' textfile`
```

note the latter is dependent on having no spaces in the file - and is a bit dangerous if the file is very large (you could run into the command-line length limit).

Comment: I want to run python mytestfile.py 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03 56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07 56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01